# Mathematical induction (power of average vs average of powers)

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, induction

I would like to prove the following statement using mathematical induction:

$\frac{(x+y)^n}{2^n}$ $\le$ $\frac{x^n+y^n}{2}$ for all $x, y$ $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$ and for all $n$ $\in$ $\mathbb{N}$.

I began with the case where $n=1$, which is not difficult at all.
However, the next step, where if the statement holds for $n$, then it also holds for $n+1$, is quite difficult for me.

I tried using the induction hypothesis (the result I can apply to the case for $n+1$ as the statement holds for $n$) and using the binomial formula, but it does not seem to work. Should I use strong mathematical induction, in this case?
 If could get some help from you, I would very much appreciate it.

Comment: Try $n=3$, $x=0$ and $y=-1$.

Comment: You need $x^{n+1}+y^{n+1}-x^ny-xy^n\ge 0$. This is true as it can be factorized as $(x-y) (x^n-y^n) $, which is nonnegative in all possible cases.

Comment: You really want $x$, $y\ge0$. This is the **power mean inequality** or at least a special case thereof. Please don't use the binomial theorem. For the induction step start off by multiplying the inequality by $\frac12(x+y)$.

Comment: @CY Kwong Thanks for your helpful comment. $(x-y)(x^n-y^n)$ $\ge$ 0 holds only when x and y $\ge$ 0, from the comment of Lord Shark the Unknown, right?

Comment: @Lord Shark the Unknown Thank you so much for your help! I really learned a lot from you!

Comment: @Kelenner Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Yes. Indeed, the inequality does not hold when $n=3$, $x=1$ and $y=-2$.

Answer (score 2):

we have to prove that
$$\frac{(x+y)^{n+1}}{2^{n+1}}\le \frac{x^{n+1}+y^{n+1}}{2}$$
multiplying $$\frac{(x+y)^n}{2^n}\le \frac{x^n+y^n}{2}$$ by $$\frac{x+y}{2}$$ we get
$$\frac{(x+y)^{n+1}}{2^{n+1}}\le \frac{1}{4}(x^{n+1}+xy^n+x^2y+y^{n+1})$$
we have to show that the right-hand side is $$\le \frac{1}{2}(x^{n+1}+y^{n+1})$$
this is equivalent to $$(x-y)(x^n-y^n)\geq 0$$ which is true.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful comment. $(x-y)(x^n-y^n)$ $\ge$ 0 holds only when x and y $\ge$ 0. Is this correct?

Comment: no, try $x=y<0$ or $x=3, y=-2... $ The condition $x,y\ge0$ is needed for the step 3 of @Dr.Sonnhard Graubner's solution above.